# Какой самый эффективный способ реализовать закрепление статьи в связке php+mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, выборка, статьи

Вот есть таблица статей, id, date, title, description, view. Как вы думаете, какой самый гуманный и правильный (проверенный вашим личным опытом) способ реализовать закрепление статьи при выборке на странице.

Допустим добавим поле [position INT(10) NOT NULL default '1'] и оно будет фигурировать в выборке под ORDER BY position ASC/DESC. Но возможны совпадения значений и путаница.

Или добавим поле [status INT(10) NOT NULL default '5'] и расписать реакцию при выборке по условиям от 1-5, где 5 это дефолтные статьи (можно и 2, это так для примера).

А вы как думаете?

Comment: если position 1 то закрепленно если 0 то нет так что всё сработает.

Comment: тогда имеет смысл ORDER BY date, position. А если допустим хочется чтобы было несколько вариантов вывода и для этого использовать display: table-header-group и display: table-footer-group

Comment: что значит как мы думаем? Вы задачу сформулируйте, а не то как мы думаем спрашивайте. Напишите что конкретно вы хотите "закрепить".

Comment: по моему и так все ясно)

Comment: @Andrew дак и с решением все очевидно, но вы начинаете придумывать какие-то непонятные вещи, поэтому начинает казаться, что может не все очевидно.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, есть таблица с полями `id, date, title, description, view`.
Для закрепления записи в топе можно добавить еще одно boolean поле `is_top`, которое будет указывать на признак размещения в топе. Допустим, что посты сортируются по дате, а `is_top = 1` означает размещение в топе. Тогда ORDER BY будет таким:

```
ORDER BY is_top desc, date
```

В результате в выборке первыми будут закрепленные посты, отсортированные по дате, а после пойдут обычные посты, так же отсортированные по дате.

Answer (score -1):

Конечно, для осмысленного ответа желательно бы точно знать, что имеется в виду под термином "закрепление статьи при выборке на странице".

Согласен, что вариант дополнительного поля "is_top" - самый гуманный и наиболее употребительный.

Если же хочется обойтись без дополнительного поля, можно просто сделать поле ID знаковым. И для закрепления/открепления статьи менять знак, не меняя значения (`UPDATE table SET id = -id`). Тогда при сортировке по возрастанию ID закреплённые будут самыми первыми. Само собой способ неприменим, если имеются FK на ID таблицы.

Comment: Менять ID дурной тон. Если правильно использовать FK, то изменение  айдишника произойдет во всех связанных ключах. Но что, если что-то работает с данными по ID в момент его замены?

Comment: Я рассматриваю простой способ осуществить задуманное. А вот соотношение профитов и граблей пусть оценивает тот, кому это реализовывать. PS. Клиент вообще не должен не то что видеть ID - даже знать о нём не должен. Это поле не для него, а для сервера. для его подсистемы контроля целостности и непротиворечивости данных. PPS. Если всё-таки ID используется клиентом, не так уж и сложно предусмотреть идентификацию по ABS(ID). При интерактивной работе с ОДНОЙ записью это допустимо.

Comment: Я имел в виду редактора постов, например. Допустим, человек открыл страницу редактирования поста, пол часа редактировал его содержимое. За это время ID у поста был сменен. Варианта развития событий два. Либо произойдет ошибка, либо добавиться новый пост.

Comment: Я тоже. Тупо `UPDATE ... WHERE ABS(id) = ABS($id)`